# Negative character length debugging in updated Visual Studio with Fortran

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I recently updated from Windows XP and Visual Studio 2005 to Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 and brought a ton of Fortran code with me (built in VS with the Intel compiler). I'm now getting several errors which may or may not be related:

1. When a subroutine of form foo(char1,real1,real2) gets called where char1 has length 200 in both the calling subroutine and in foo, I get *"forrtl: severe (408): fort: (18): Dummy character variable 'char1' has length 200 which is greater than actual variable length -858993460 Image PC Routine Line Source libifcoremdd.dll 02AED3FE Unknown Unknown Unknown Stack trace terminated abnormally"*  I looked around and that number seems to be a hex address (0xcccccccc) converted to an integer.  Why would it be passing a nonsense address instead of the length?
2. When I try to debug the problem I set a break point at the subroutine call and try to step in I get an error *"No Source Available No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed"*.
3. I also noticed I'm getting a few dozen *"Cannot find or open the PDB file."* errors for things that don't seem directly related to my source code.

Unfortunately the error is embedded in thousands of lines of proprietary code so I can't post it all and I can't reproduce the error with a simple example.

Anyone have any suggestions of things to try? Thanks!

Comment: Did you rebuild all when you moved to the new platform?  Most of the symptoms you describe can be explained by old object code being linked into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

No symbols...Source code is all related to the .pdb file.  The pdb file is generated when you build the code.  It is like a map of who lives where and where every line of code is.  If you try setting a breakpoint and you get a filled red circle, it can find the pdb.  If you just get an empty grey circle, it can't find the pdb file.  Copy the pdb file from where you built the code to where the executable is and that should cure that problem.  Unfortunately after copying the file, you need to come out of visual studio and go back in.  It doesn't read the pdb immediately you put it there.

As for your uninitialized variable error (everything gets filled with c), have you done a clean build?  If you've moved from XP to W7, is it XP32 to W764?  Did you just move the sources or the objects as well.  If so, is your executable a x86/win32 or x64 or bits of both?  Try building everything as x86/win32 first.  See if that doesn't work, then have a look at the code generation options: are they all MT, MTD, MD or MDD?  They should all be the same.  Mixing them is a disaster waiting to happen (normally when you're demonstrating to some high ranking officer).